# Standarization for each column in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to randomize data frame 100x5 from multivariate normal distribution. Then I want to make a standardization for each value in that data frame with respect to column. i.e.  I want to replace:

[image]

where

[image]

[image]

and in vector x letter 'i' refers to number of vector (1..5) and 'j' refers to j-th value of i-th vector.

And I wanted to do it *without any loops*.

**My work so far**

```
import numpy
import pandas
#create some really numbers by randomly pressing keyboard
mean = [1, 2,3,4,5]
cov = [[1, 0,0,4,6], [0, 100,4,6,1],[12,14,1,0,13],
       [41,5,0,3,6],[123,5,1,5,12]]
x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5 = numpy.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 5000).T

#Create data frame
df=(pandas.DataFrame([x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5]))


#Try to do standardization

df_norm = (df - df.mean()) / (df.stdev())
```

And I have the problem : last line is not working. It's very intuitive for me that it should work but it doesn't. Could you please help me with my problem ?

Also I would have an additional question. After that standardization I want to estimate from which multivariate normal distribution sample comes from. Do we have any implemented function to do so ?

Comment: Do you mean `(df-df.mean())/df.std()`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this by column.

```
df_norm = df.copy()
for col in df:
    df_norm[col] = (df[col] - df[col].mean()) / df[col].std()
```

Comment: As wrote in my question : I'm looking for solution without loops